# MongoDB aggregate geoNear in lookup pipeline not behaving like documentation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm basing my code from [this example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#-geonear-with-the-let-option) to perform a lookup (left join) then a geoNear.

```js
    db.jobs.aggregate([
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "companies",
          "localField": "company",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "company",
          "pipeline": [
            {
              "$geoNear": {
                "near": {
                  "type": "Point",
                  "coordinates": [
                    -80,
                    44
                  ],
                  
                },
                "key": "company.geo",
                "distanceField": "distance"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ])
```

I've created a [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iKU1ub5CfdV)

I'm getting the error

```
$geoNear is only valid as the first stage in an optimized pipeline
```

How do I perform a geoNear in a lookup pipeline? Removing the pipeline shows the joined document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is that you used a concise syntax for `$lookup`. From the [official document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-a-concise-correlated-subquery-with--lookup),

> The new concise syntax removes the requirement for an equality match on the foreign and local fields inside of an $expr operator in a $match stage.

So the matching between `localField` and `foreignField` is treated as the first stage of the sub-pipeline.

Solution: You can simply move the clause to another `$match` stage after `$geoNear`

```js
db.jobs.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "companies",
      "let": {
        company: "$company"
      },
      "as": "company",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                -80,
                44
              ],
              
            },
            "key": "company.geo",
            "distanceField": "distance"
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$company"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Mongo Playground seems cannot demonstrate the behaviour for this case since it involves the usage of 2d-index. But I put [it](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JcCxJlSHLa8) here nevertheless.

Comment: It seems to partially work, I'm losing the joined document in the result

Comment: @Eric could you check if the issue is related to the `key` clause in `$geoNear`? I changed it a bit to make it work in my local MongoDB. And, I have reverted the answer to your version now.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: @Eric what do you mean by *losing the joined document*? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: company is empty in the result. If i remove the pipeline, I see the full linked document as job.company

Comment: see https://mongoplayground.net/p/yRAYVYQPqWr

Comment: It is working completely fine in my local [mongodb setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYJp5.png); except I need to change from `company.geo` from your original example to `geo` since I build 2d-index on the field `geo`. Can you cross-compare if that is causing the difference between the behaviours of yours and my side?

Comment: Oh yea it's because job.company is saved as string so I use $project and $toObjectId to convert it first to MongoID.... not sure how to fix that but what you did works

Comment: Figured the rest it out, thanks a lot, you helped greatly